# Jquery backwards tree traversal

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm looking for a solution to a little problem I have, currently I'm looking to get the entire DOM tree from an element (e.g. all the parents), which I can do using `.closest('body').first()`.

The problem is I'm looking for a way to go through each element and parent and remove all of the text/html from them except the original target, so basically have a blank tree but have html in the bottom element.

Although I haven't tried it *yet*, I was thinking just `.each()` might work, although something tells me it would have a problem with the nested structure?

Any advice would be great!

Thanks
Dom

**UPDATE:**
Accepted answer works great! I adapted the code and added to the fiddle below to allow it to work with deep nested structures like the ones I was working with...

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/RDNTc/2/

Comment: I don't think `.nearest()` is in jquery

Comment: Sorry - I meant `.closest()`, edited the Q

Comment: How about `.parents()` If you can post a fiddle then it will be easy to help. http://api.jquery.com/parents/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That script remove every text nodes of the parent of the target :

```
$('p').parentsUntil('body').each(function(){
    $(this).contents().each(function(){
        if(this.nodeType === 3) this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDNTc/;

Comment: @Dom i don't understand what you mean. What is shown in the console is exactly doing what your code intend to do : `<div><div><div><p id="1404924426470">Yes, bla</p></div></div></div> <div> bloh <div> <div> <div>show me</div> bleuh <p id="1404924426470">Show that bla</p> </div> bli </div> bloh </div>`. No text in the first 3 opening div.

Comment: Nevermind, was my own error in the middle. I've updated my Q now again!

Answer (score 0):

You can traverse up the parents in jQuery using [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/). Then use `.each()` to iterate over them in a loop.